# KVM: Ubuntu host having a Win 10 as client - attach my data drive to the client?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, kvm

Normally i use networking to exchange files between my KVM VM and the host, its not the most smooth implementation as you need to reboot when things go idle etc - but when it works it works.

But now i am in a serious problem here - i am at a hotel connected to WIFI on my linux host, and now my VM cant get network connection.

What i just need here is to be able to share files between the 2 without being networked - drag and drop doesnt work on KVM, and was thinking it might would be easy to just attach my /media/user//Data Drive/ whcih is my secondary harddrive on the host - and then be able to access that from the windows client.

But that appears to be complicated at best ? anyone can help how im able to do that - and remember client is Windows.

edit : i can use a USB stick and thats how i sorted my immediate problem - but why should it be so complicated to attach a drive out of the box ?

Comment: ok i gave up on KVM and converted my client to VirtualBox and can now drag and drop and seems to be alot better with networking too

Answer (score 0):

While i wasnt able to get KVM to work if anyone else is dealing with this issue, what i did instead was to convert the image to VirtualBox by doing this :

```
qemu-img convert -O vdi windows10.qcow2 windows10.vdi
```

And then in VirtualBox i created a new Windows10 and attached the VDI as HDD and then it all booted up and i was up running again and can now drag & drop files with no hazzle.